# Localstorage value not reseting on page refresh

Tags: javascript, local-storage

user selected value from select box is set in to button value but it (LocalStorage) value is changing on page refresh(F5)

```js
function change(){
        var opt = $("#gsb_tb option:selected").text();
        var stored =  localStorage.setItem('project',JSON.stringify(opt));
        var valueofstore= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('project'));
        document.getElementById("set-project").value= valueofstore;
    }
```

```html
<select id="gsb_tb" style="height: 45px; width: 78%; margin-left: 70px; padding-right: 90px; vertical-align: middle;" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select your Project</option>
<option value="370"> E-Card</option>
<option value="278">Labs</option>
<option value="196">Absolute DB</option>

<input value="Set as Working Project" onclick="change()" aria-label="I'm Feeling Lucky" name="btnI" class='center-btn' jsaction="sf.lck" type="submit" id='set-project'>
```

Comment: You seems to be missing `)` after `localStorage.setItem('project',JSON.stringify(opt);` . It will be `JSON.stringify(opt));`

Comment: There is a syntax errror, after the `JSON.stringify(opt)` one `) `is missing

Comment: Yea!it is working ,but however, now it  reset on page refresh

Comment: Check in developer console for any js errors

Comment: Nope, I checked, no errors

Comment: Why would you expect it NOT to reset on a page reload?

Comment: I need it to use, on next few pages or until & unless user does not clear browser cache, so once a project selected ,I will be skipping this step,  next time user visit this page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand, you might be looking for `window.onload`

```
function change(){
    var opt = $("#gsb_tb option:selected").text();
    var stored =  localStorage.setItem('project',JSON.stringify(opt));
    var valueofstore= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('project'));
    console.log(valueofstore)
    document.getElementById("set-project").value= valueofstore;
}
function load(){
    var valueofstore= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('project'));
    console.log(valueofstore)
    if (valueofstore){
        document.getElementById("set-project").value= valueofstore;
    }
}
window.onload = load;
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean your selected and saved value to the localStorage is not reflected when you refresh your page right?

If that's right, there's nothing wrong with the saving to localStorage, but you need to restore the value to select > option value.

Comment: I didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

You need to load the data from the local storage on page load

```
<select id="gsb_tb" style="height: 45px; width: 78%; margin-left: 70px; padding-right: 90px; vertical-align: middle;" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select your Project</option>
<option value="370"> E-Card</option>
<option value="278">Labs</option>
<option value="196">Absolute DB</option>
</select>

<button value="s" type="button" id='set-project'>Change</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var project = localStorage.getItem('project');
  if(undefined !== project && project != "")
  {
    document.getElementById("set-project").innerHTML = project;
  }

    $("#set-project").on("click", update);

})

function update(){
    var opt = $("#gsb_tb option:selected").text();
    var stored =  localStorage.setItem('project',opt);
    var valueofstore= localStorage.getItem('project');
    document.getElementById("set-project").value= valueofstore;
    document.getElementById("set-project").innerHTML= valueofstore;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vw333m10/)

Comment: do you want the text of the button to be change on user click? see the updated answer